# r shiny arguments imply diffrering number of rows :1 0

Tags: r, shiny

I can't display a outputable. I used radioButtons and I wanted to change to Selectinput and now it doesn't work. I searched and tried many solutions but nothing work. Maybe I should not have modified too much code without try...

Here my ui :

```
ui<-tagList(
     navbarPage(
          "Exploitation Dérivés UGA",

          tabPanel("Analyse Portefeuille",
                   # Application title
                   titlePanel("Analyse Portefeuille"),

                   # Sidebar with a slider input for number of bins 
                   #sidebarLayout(
                        sidebarPanel(

                             selectInput("Asset","Produit :",
                                         choices = c("Call","Put","Forward","Future")),

                             selectInput("selection","Sous-jaccent :",
                                         choices = c("Devise","Action","Future")),  

                             br(),
                             numericInput("stock",
                                          "Prix sous-jaccent:",
                                          1,step = 0.0001),
                             numericInput("strike",
                                          "Strike:",
                                          1,step = 0.0001),
                             numericInput("qte",
                                          "Quantité :",
                                          1),
                             numericInput("prix",
                                          "Prix :",
                                          1,step = 0.0001),
                             numericInput("vol",
                                          "Volatilité Implicite:",
                                          0.25,step = 0.0001),
                             numericInput("maturite en Nb de jour",
                                          "Maturité :",
                                          30,step = 1),
                             numericInput("taux_rf",
                                          "Taux:",
                                          0.123,step = 0.001),
                             numericInput("taux_ext",
                                          "Taux:",
                                          0.123,step = 0.001),
                             numericInput("nb_hedg",
                                          "Période de Hedging:",
                                          30,step = 1),
                             actionButton("add","Ajouter"),
                             actionButton("reset","Réinitialiser"),
                             textInput("nom",
                                       "Nom stratégie:",
                                       "Nom stratégie"),
                             actionButton("save","Sauver Portefeuille")
                        ),

                        # Show a plot of the generated distribution
                        mainPanel(
                             tabsetPanel(type="tabs",
                                         tabPanel("Portefeuille",tableOutput("Portefeuille")),
                                         tabPanel("Plot",plotlyOutput("Plot")),
                                         tabPanel("tableau",DT::dataTableOutput("tableau1"),
                                                  DT::dataTableOutput("tableau2")),
                                         tabPanel("Surface",plotlyOutput("Surface1"),
                                                  plotlyOutput("Surface2"))
                             )
                        )#)
          )
```

))

And now the server code :

```
shinyServer(function(input, output) {

## Premier onglet, Analyse Portefeuille

  dist<-reactive({
       switch(input$Asset,
              "Call"=1,
              "Put"=-1,
              "Forward"=0,
              "Future"=0)
  })

  dataInput<-eventReactive(input$add, {

       temp<-read.csv("C://Users//Administrator//Documents//strategie_derive//portefeuilles//temp.csv",sep=",",dec=".",header = TRUE)
       temp<-temp[,-1]

       disti<-dist()

       tempi<-data.frame(Type=disti,
                  Stock=input$stock,
                  Strike=input$strike,
                  Qte=input$qte,
                  Prix=input$prix,
                  Vol=input$vol,
                  Mat=input$maturite,
                  Taux1=input$taux_rf,
                  Taux2=input$taux_ext,
                  Periode=input$nb_hedg,
                  Sjct=input$selection,
                  Prdt=input$Asset)

       if (temp$Prix[1]==0){
            temp<-tempi
       } else {
            temp<-rbind(temp,tempi)
       }
       write.csv(temp,"C://Users//Administrator//Documents//strategie_derive//portefeuilles//temp.csv")
       temp
  })

  output$Portefeuille<-renderTable({
       if (input$add==0) {
            temp<-read.csv("C://Users//Administrator//Documents//strategie_derive//portefeuilles//temp.csv",sep=",",dec=".",header = TRUE)
            temp<-temp[,-1]
            temp
       } else { dataInput()}

  })
```

It's the eventReactive(input$Add) which does't work, when I click I get the error message.

Answer (score 0):

The problem raised here, in definition of your data frame.

```
disti<-dist()

   tempi<-data.frame(Type=disti,
              Stock=input$stock,
              Strike=input$strike,
              Qte=input$qte,
              Prix=input$prix,
              Vol=input$vol,
              Mat=input$maturite,
              Taux1=input$taux_rf,
              Taux2=input$taux_ext,
              Periode=input$nb_hedg,
              Sjct=input$selection,
              Prdt=input$Asset)
```

Object `dist()` has length 0, while others have length 1. Date frame needs same length for all variables included.

Comment: ok thanks, but how could I fix it ? Why dist() has a length of 0, i call the function to get a number...